# Passing association parameters on ActiveRecord object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

In my application I have 2 classes like this:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  attr_accessible :title, :city_id
end
```

If I create city object:

```
city = City.create!(:name => 'My city')
```

and then pass parameters to create event like this:

```
event = Event.create!(:name => 'Some event', :city => city)
```

I get

```
event.city_id => null
```

So the question is - is it possible to pass parameters in such a way to get my objects connected, what am I doing wrong? Or should I use other ways (like

```
event.city = city
```

)
?

Comment: I've just created city and event models the same as yours and using your code from above the event is successfully created and associated with the city. What version of Rails are you using? Are you testing this using `script/console` ?

Comment: Yes, I tested with script/console, rails version is 2.3.5

Comment: Same version that I'm using here then. Is there any other code in your models?

Comment: I don't see the same behavior on my machine. I'm running Rails 2.3.5 on Ruby 1.8.7. As long as the `City.create!` call succeeds, it will return a *saved* `City` that has an `id`. Creating an `Event` with `:city => (a saved city with an id)` will also populate the `Event`'s `city_id`. Perhaps the problem is use of `attr_accessor` or `attr_protected`?

Comment: Please, see the update and my last comment to the second answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally this happens when you have an `attr_accessor` that excludes or an `attr_protected` that includes the `:city` attribute on `Event`. Allowing `:city_id` to be accessible does *not* automatically allow `:city` to be so.

(NB: this answer provided as per the discussion in comments above, and thus community-wiki.)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
city = City.create!(:name => "London")

event = Event.create!(:name => "Big Event")
event.city = city
event.save
```

Alternatively, if `Event.validates_presence_of :city`, and thus the `Event.create!` call will fail without a `City`, you could do this:

```
event = Event.new(:name => 'Big Event').tap do |e|
  e.city = city
  e.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
event = Event.create!(:name => 'Some event', :city_id => city.id)
```

Comment: I know, that I can do it this way. I'm asking if it is possible to pass parameters as I described.

Comment: well, your models don't get saved - probably validation fails on city being blank - do you want more proofs that it couldn't work? :)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question :( 
I meant "event.city_id", not "event.id". Objects are saved, but they are not connected.

Comment: `create!` would raise an exception if validation fails

Comment: @mikej, good point, forgot about that

@LightAlloy, your objects aren't connected because there's no such thing as `city` in your `Event`'s attributes hash, there's only `city_id`. To get your objects connected you should fill `city_id` which is not happening in your case - you're effectively assigning `city.id` to an inexistent `city` attribute.

Comment: @neutrino you're wrong that `City.new` (or its brethren `build` and `create`) won't understand the `:city` key. As long as `Event.belongs_to :city` or `Event.has_one :city` (the former is true in this case) *and* `:city` is not a protected attribute (by inclusion in `attr_protected` or exclusion from `attr_accessible`), `City` is perfectly happy with translating that key into an `id` and will even cache the instance so it doesn't do a lookup the next time you request `my_event.city`.

Comment: Actually there is attr_accessible line in my class.
It is like 

attr_accessible :name, :city_id

Doesn't city_id in this list allow me to pass both city and city_id parameters?

Comment: @LightAlloy: aha :) No, `attr_accessible` is *very* strict. Setting `city_id` to accessible does *not* confer privileges to the corresponding `city`. You can simply add `city` to the list, but you probably want to *replace* `city_id` with `city`... *unless* you have a `<form>` with a `<select>` of cities to choose from, in which case the controller's call to `update` will probably pass a `city_id` rather than a `City` instance. In that case, you'd want both in the `attr_accessible` list.